# I want to ask the user if he want to quit or write again

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```
import pyttsx3

robot = pyttsx3.init()

while True:
 robot.say(input('Write something that you need me to say:\n'))
 robot.runAndWait()

 n = (input('if you need to quit type : quit , if you need to write again 
 press any button\n'))

 if n == 'Quit' or 'quit' or 'QUIT':
  break
 else:
  continue
```

I want to ask the user if he want to quit or write again but when I run my code it breaks the loop any way.

Comment: please post code not an image of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what those robot lines are doing so I commented them out since they are not related to the bug I found in your code. I got this to work by correcting your use of `or` statements and using case insensitive check instead:

```
import pyttsx3

robot = pyttsx3.init()

while True:
  # robot.say(input('Write something that you need me to say:\n'))
  # robot.runAndWait()

  n = (input('if you need to quit type : quit , if you need to write again press any button\n'))

  if n.lower() == 'quit':
    print("quitting...\n")
    break
  else:
    print("continuing...\n")
    continue
```

**Explanation**:

You wrote `if n == 'Quit' or 'quit' or 'QUIT'` -  which means "If n equals 'Quit' or if 'quit' is truthy (it is) or 'QUIT' is truthy (it is), proceed this way: `break`" hence the termination you saw. If you wanted to use `or` correctly, the expression would need to read:

```
if n == 'Quit' or n == 'quit' or n == 'QUIT
```

Comment: I don't know what is change in the core of your code but it worked , thank you